# How to use method overload by using Generic c#

Tags: c#, generics

we often overload method sometime also overload constructor. is there anyway to reduce method overload using generic as a result we will create one generic method and call with different parameter different time from the application. can anyone please explain with sample code how to do it. is it possible at all.

Comment: Please consider to add some code that describes your current situation.

Comment: I doubt you'd get any benefit trying to replace overloaded methods with some generic one.  Normally with an overload goes different behavior.  Then your generic method would need to implement different behavior for different types and that only complicates the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, generic methods provide *the same functionaility* to different types.

It looks like you want *different functionality* for different types.

Polymorphism is the tool you need to use to achieve this, not generics.